# How to rotate the background image in css?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have a custom radiobutton image. I am trying to rotate the background image alone when some one chooses the option. But it rotates the the whole div.

here is my partially working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwaran/UB72d/5/)

```
ul.pt-answers > li > label > input:checked +img {  
    background: url(http://www.opinionpoll.in/files/images/vote_symbol.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-size:30px 30px;
    -webkit-animation:spin 0.5s ease 1 both;
    -moz-animation:spin 0.5s ease 1 both;
    animation:spin 0.5s ease 1 both;
    border:none;

}


@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(30deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(30deg); } }
```

Comment: There is one thing I would like to say is the preloading does not work (at least for the image URL in your fiddle and tested on Opera). I'm not sure why it does not work but trying another image URL (such as the http://placekitten.com/30/30) works great. Looks like there is something wrong with the image URL (cheating the browsers from caching) but it's obvisouly a normaly image URL, the reason why image caching does not work is still unclear to me. Does it work for you? on which browsers?

Comment: No. It is not working for me either. I do not know the reason too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the `<div>` element tag instead of `<img>` so you can create a pseudo `::before` element in it. You can specify the css select to create the pseudo `::before` element, assign the background properties and apply the spin, viola!

You can see what I mean [in your updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UB72d/7/).

Get additional information [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/).

edit: spelling

Comment: It's a good idea, however: once the div is placed there is no way for the user to uncheck the checkbox because the div overlays the checkbox. So you cannot use it all, unfortunately.

Comment: @BramVanroy  it is radiobutton FYI. so you are saying I can't use it? It seems to be working fine though

Comment: Apparently, it is never an issue since the div is a child of the input, therefore, clicking the child div will also trigger a click to the input. Moreover, the OP's example is using radio buttons, you can never uncheck a radio button once checked unless you select another. You can fiddle with the checkbox version here to see that it is working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/UB72d/8/

Comment: Also, the css select does not add anything except the pseudo ::before element inside the already existing <div>. I cannot see how it can interfere with the user actions.